# Use custom polymer elements in own project - How to do it right?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer, web-component

So I found this nice port of Chart.js as a polymer component on [customelements.io](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-chart) but I'm not able to use them in my polymer.dart project. I copied all the files from the library project into my project and fixed the paths but the elements are not showing up. I get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined chart-bar.html:27(anonymous function) chart-bar.html:27
```

(+ same error for the other files from the library proj).

I have no bower.json in my project (but a pubspec.yaml) and I'm wondering if I need one because the library project got one in there?

So what is the right way to get those polymer elements into my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no straight-forward way to use Polymer.js polymer elements in a Polymer.dart project.
You can try to generate Dart wrappers using https://github.com/dart-lang/custom-element-apigen / https://pub.dartlang.org/search?q=custom-element-apigen.

The code generation depends on proper JavaScript codedoc in the JS elements which is often incomplete but I have heard of people who were satisfied by the result (Dart core_elements/paper_elements are generated with this but there is also manual work involved).

Comment: Oh okay. Well thats a pitty. I'll look into the apigen. Do you know if there is development going on in this direction?

Comment: There are different attempts. `custom-element-apigen` and improving Dart-JS-interop. I'm not up-to-date about the development of the 2nd and whether/how this will improve the interop story with Polymer.js elements but there is always a lot going on improving the dev experience.

Comment: You know, this might not be clear to everyone! Is it documented somewhere that javascript web components are incompatible with a dart webpage? You'd think that web components are encapsulated enough that you don't have to know what script language they use.

Comment: Polymer. js elements are not incompatible. You can just use them in Polymer.dart pages. Not so easy is it to interact with them from Dart code.